# How can get set properties be covered in test class

Tags: code-coverage

How can the following be covered in test class:

```
public list<object__c> lrecords {get{
list<object__c> = [select id,name from object__c where id in=:setIds];}
set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note** Generally, you should ***NOT*** have to do this. If the property is not covered during normal testing one of two things could be going on:

1. Property is not needed as it is not accessed within your code and thus not organically covered
2. Your tests are not covering the business requirements and the locations where the property is used is not covered.

You should be reviewing why it is not covered rather than trying to force cover the getter.

All you need to do is access them and as such it should happen organically. If it does not, review why

One example to force coverage (however read the above, it is important):

```
system.assertEquals(false,[xyz].lrecords.isEmpty(),'No Object__c records were returned');
```

When, how, they type of assert, etc all depend on what you are doing in your class.